# Full-width bootstrap image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, width

Good evening,

I'm trying to put a full-width image as the home page of my project, and I'm using Bootstrap, but I can't manage to avoid the white margins all around the picture whether a only put , or I frame it with a  or a  as suggested in the answers I read...

Here's my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag("diversite_anglais.png", :alt => "Travail interculturel") %>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper"><div class="btn-group btn-lg btn-justified">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">OUR SERVICES</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">OUR NETWORK</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">OUR PARTNERS</button>
</div></span>
```

And my CSS :

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  }

.container > img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Changes :

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="wrapper"><div class="btn-group btn-lg btn-justified">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">OUR SERVICES</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">OUR NETWORK</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">OUR PARTNERS</button>
</div></span>

</body>

</html>


.navbar-header {
    padding: 20px;
 }

.navbar-brand {
    float:none;
}

.btn {
    margin: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 35%;
    right: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font: bold 30px 'Roboto', Sans-Serif;
    padding: 10px;
}

html { 
  background: url(diversite_anglais.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

PROBLEM SOLVED :

```
$navbar-margin-bottom: -20px;
```

Comment: Like this? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

Comment: bootstrap has a default navbar:`navbar navbar-default`. I'd suggest you provide this css to your navbar `box-shadow: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-ms-border-radius: 0;
-o-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
text-shadow: none;` and remove any padding you might have. Let me know if that works

Comment: It doesn't change anything... :(

Comment: I found the answer !! it takes : $navbar-margin-bottom: -20px;

Comment: Awesome! if you think my answer helped please check it as the accepted one. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
   html {
      background: url(..img/yourimagefile) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

I would use `html` instead of the `.container` just to make sure because it's always at least the height of the browser window.

Drop the `image_tag`, instead use the **css** above.

More details [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Works fine, but I still get a margin between the navbar and the picture : http://0.0.0.0:3000/

Comment: That link didn't help as it is only your local host. Could you update your questions with the relevant html and css?

Comment: It only moves the navbar, but not the white margin... But providing my code won't help, as I didn't changed anything except what you provided me

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from Bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

But otherwise, make sure there's no margins and padding around the image or containing divs. If you use the example template above though, it should work fine.